# Xcode 10.1 opening wrong file

Tags: xcode, xcode10.1

Just downloaded Xcode 10.1. I have Preferences->Navigation->Double Click Navigation set to 'Uses Seperate Window' as I usually do. However double clicking any file in the project opens a window but the contents of that window is the wrong file. Whichever file I double click on, the same incorrect file opens. If I change double clicking to open in a tab, the correct file is opened...

The problem appears to be just one project.

Have tried a 'Clean Build Folder' to no avail

It was working fine in 10.0

I open the project using the xxxx.xcworkspace (as I have pods in the project).

If I open a new window and view a specific file there then go back to my window with the list of files and double click that file, the correct window is brought to the front with the correct file visible.

Comment: Interestingly I just double clicked a file name while my mac was very busy and noticed that the *correct* file was displayed for a moment before the incorrect one. So I can tap the left arrow to go back to the correct file. Even weirder...

Comment: Same thing happening to me, so at least you know it's a bug with Xcode 10.1.  I've not been able to find a fix.  Annoying to always have to tap the left arrow every time I open up a new window.

Comment: Same thing happening to me. In my project it's the Readme that's opened. Tried all sorts of things and can't get it to open any other file.

Comment: Frustratingly this problem has just gone away. I haven't changed anything about the project (deliberately anyway). Same version of XCode. There gave been a couple of restarts and XCode did crash at one point. But no pointers to help either Phamer or drekka I'm afraid

Comment: Yes I am also getting bit by this atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. For me it's the Readme.md file that is added at the top level of the project (not inside a group). Removing the reference from the project or putting the top level file(s) in a group (folder) fixed the issue.